# Bad JSON: expected object value. Dropbox API file upload error

Tags: file-upload, dropbox-api, dropbox-java

I am trying to upload file to Dropbox using dropbox java sdk

I created a app in dropbox, gave permission to write, app status is Development.

The code works till "write mode done" logger, it fails after that. **fileStream** is of type InputStream

```
DbxClientV2 client = createClient();
    String path = "/" + fileName.toString();
    try {
        System.out.println("STARTING...............");
        UploadBuilder ub = client.files().uploadBuilder(path);
        System.out.println("ub done");
        ub.withMode(WriteMode.ADD);
        System.out.println("write mode done");
        FileMetadata metadata = ub.uploadAndFinish(fileStream);
        System.out.println("File uploaded");
        System.out.println(metadata.toStringMultiline());
        ;
        System.out.println("FINISHED...............");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception I get is

```
com.dropbox.core.BadResponseException: Bad JSON: expected object value.
at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.unexpectedStatus(DbxRequestUtil.java:347)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.unexpectedStatus(DbxRequestUtil.java:324)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxUploader.finish(DbxUploader.java:268)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxUploader.uploadAndFinish(DbxUploader.java:126)
.
.
.
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: expected object value.
at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.dropbox.core.stone.StoneSerializer.expectStartObject(StoneSerializer.java:91)
at com.dropbox.core.ApiErrorResponse$Serializer.deserialize(ApiErrorResponse.java:53)
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Bad-JSON-expected-object-value-exception-while-uplaoding-a-file/m-p/454732#M23470 ]

Comment: The call was returning 401 status code. Regenerating the access token solved the issue.